# cannot add configurable product to cart in magento

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart, configurable-product

i want to add a product to cart in magento , product details is :

```
type = configurable
product id = 1300
product sku = FCC100
Attribute Code= color
Attribute Label= color
Attribute Id= 152
options value = 28,43
options label = blue,red
```

this configurable product have two color option red and blue, there is two simple product atached to this configurable product.

i try with this code :

```
 $product = array(
    "product_id" =>"1300",
    "qty" => 2,
    "super_attribute" => array(152 => 28));
    $result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionID, $cartID, array($product));
```

but this code return me this message :

> please specify product option(s)

i use this code to add simple product and it`s work fine :

```
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionID, $cartID, array(array(
        'product_id' =>   $productID  ,
        'sku' =>  $sku  ,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'options' =>array(0 =>array('key' => $option1id ,'value' => $option1value),1 =>array('key' => $option2id ,'value' => $option2value)),

        'bundle_option' => null,
        'bundle_option_qty' => null,
        'links' => null
        )));
```

my problem is with configurable product. i try to add with simple child products but problem of this way is often child products have not price and price is setted to parent product.
what is the problem in my code ? is there any way to add configurable product to cart with out using API ?

this is what i found in product page source:

```
Product.Config({"attributes":{"152":{"id":"152","code":"color","label":"\u0631\u0646\u06af","options":[{"id":"28","label":"\u0622\u0628\u06cc","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["1301"]},{"id":"47","label":"\u0632\u0631\u0634\u06a9\u06cc","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["1302"]}]}},"template":"#{price}\u00a0\u0631\u06cc\u0627\u0644","basePrice":"550000","oldPrice":"550000","productId":"1300","chooseText":"\u0627\u0646\u062a\u062e\u0627\u0628 \u06cc\u06a9 \u06af\u0632\u06cc\u0646\u0647...","taxConfig":{"includeTax":false,"showIncludeTax":false,"showBothPrices":false,"defaultTax":0,"currentTax":0,"inclTaxTitle":"\u0634\u0627\u0645\u0644 \u0645\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u0627\u062a"}});
```

Comment: The error is clear, you're not passing in the `options` which Magento requires to add the item to the cart.

Comment: @Alex i pass value of option, 28 is value for blue

Answer (score 2):

**Your array must be like below**

```
$arrProducts = array(
array(
    "product_id" =>"21",
    "qty" => 2,
            "super_attribute" => array(         
                92 => 162

             )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$product` array is missing the `options` key values.

You need to add `options` which should be **An array in the form of option_id => content** per the documentation.

```
$product = array(
              "product_id" => "1300",
              "qty" => 2,
              "options" => array(         
                                152 => 28
                           )
              );
```

Documentation: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html

Comment: i change supper_attribute with options but still i get same message

Comment: i add product attribute info to question, please look at that, thanks

Comment: @mahdi , have you got any solution to this problem ?

Comment: I am also get the same error,Have anybody got the solution.Please help.